# JQuery removing area element not working

Tags: jquery, html, dictionary, area

The area element with the ID of "rd" is what I want removed:
    `<area alt="yellow" id="yd" href="#"  shape="rect" coords="245,243,443,639" />`
    `<area alt="red" id="rd" href="#"  shape="rect" coords="674,247,850,638" />`

My function to do this:

```
$("#yd").on("click", function () {
    $("#rd").remove();
});
```

As soon as I click on the area that has the ID 'yd', the 'rd' element should be removed from my understanding but it still remains, even after cleaning, rebuilding, unloading, and reloading the project. All being done in MVC / VS 2017.

The function is in an external .js file which is being rendered in a @section at the bottom of the view page. I used a simple alert function to make sure they were linked properly and they are.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console? Can you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: There are no errors in the browser console. I'l see if i can somehow make an example of what is happening

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/apv7onzy/

Comment: In your example, the jQuery library was not included. Once included, the code seems to work as intended. [Test here](https://jsfiddle.net/apv7onzy/2/).

Comment: that is quite odd. I have the jQuery library included in the @section but it still will not remove the #rd i am specifying

Answer (score 0):

Place your on click method inside document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#yd").on("click", function () {
         $("#rd").remove();

     });

});
```

Comment: This could be the case. But the OP says the JavaScript is included at the bottom of the page, so waiting for the document to be ready shouldn't be necessary. The elements should already exist in the DOM before the JavaScript is executed.

Comment: @n1njatron You mention that the area is being rendered, is there a callback function you can use to bind your click event? If the area is being rendered asynchronously, then your click event was binded before the area existed in the dom.